# Stack Overflow of 8086 microprocessor

Tags: assembly, stack-overflow, x86-16, callstack, microprocessors

What'll be the behaviour of the 8086 Microprocessor when the stack is full and even then I push something into it?

Answer (score 6):

On the 8086, a PUSH instruction or implicit stack push will decrement the SP register by two and store the appropriate quantity at SS:SP (i.e. 16*SS+SP).  If the SP register was $0000, the data will go to SS:$FFFE.  If the SP register was $0001, the MSB of the data will go to SS:$0000 and the LSB will go to SS:$FFFF.  The processor will not take any special notice of the stack wraparound.  While stack wraparound would typically be a bad thing, there are some situations on the 8086 where it could be ignored at wouldn't affect anything.  For example, if SS pointed to 64K of RAM that wasn't needed for anything else, and a program which was never going to exit sometimes restarted itself by simply calling "main()" without resetting the stack, the stack could wrap around without affecting program operation, since all effective-address calculations would wrap around the same way.

Note that on the 80386 and later processors, the stack-underflow behavior is changed.  PUSH, CALL, etc. use 32-bit (or 64-bit) address calculations, rather than 16-bit, and those wrap to $FFFFFFFF (or $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) rather than $FFFF.

Comment: This is a great answer! would you be able to cite you're source on this? If it's in the 8086 Family User's Manual a page number would be great. The reason is that I'm trying to write an emulator and I'm trying to use official documentation for as much of the implementation as possible (I'm citing my code).

Comment: I don't have the reference manual handy, so I can't give you a cite.  I don't even recall the manual addressing that particular situation, though I remember having seen articles mentioning such issues in discussing how later processors aren't quite 8086-compatible.  If I remember, I may have a chance to play a little with an actual 8088-based machine over the next few days, since it's not hard to imagine that a push when SP equals 0001 might store the LSB at data at SP:$FFFF and the MSB in the next higher byte, rather than SP:$0000, but I'm pretty sure that's not what it does.

Comment: 386 in real mode still uses SS:SP.  The docs: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push Operation section has an `ELSE (* StackAddrSize = 16 *)` case that uses SS:SP.  So I think it would be more appropriate to say "note that in 32-bit mode"...

Comment: @PeterCordes: See the last paragraph of "Description".  I think my main point remains valid, though I tweaked it somewhat.

Answer (score 5):

The 8086 has no 'protected mode', therefore no 'guard page at the bottom of the stack', therefore no well-defined exception. Instead your push will overwrite whatever code or data is below the bottom of the stack, which will eventually (but not immediately) result in "undefined behaviour" if that code is executed or that data is used.

Answer (score 3):

There is no end. I mean the stack in these processors has a reverse order (from right to left).
So it will go on up to a rom block or the end of memory. This causes an exception in the processor  wich could soft reset itself.