# in 8086 after the stack gets full, where does an extra byte pushed into the stack will be saved?

Tags: stack, x86-16, microprocessors

in Intel 8086 microprocessor, assume SS=1000H and SP= 0100H

After the stack gets full, where does an extra byte pushed into the stack will be saved? give the physical address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stack Overflow of 8086 microprocessor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485349/stack-overflow-of-8086-microprocessor)

Comment: My answer is "stack overflow", which is kind of funny because you ask this question on - yes ... - stack overflow

Answer (score 2):

PUSH decrements SP by two and then stores two bytes of data at SS:SP. So, if you PUSH when SP=0, the two bytes of data get written at SS:0xFFFE. You should now be able to complete the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Twenty five years ago I taught 8086 assembler programming, it's a bit vague now. I am pretty sure that if you add more items to the stack it simply overwrites what was there beyond it. It is up to the programmer to ensure that sufficient stack space is available so that this does not happen. And to arrange the program so that you know that it will not keep adding items to the stack in a runaway fashion. Or to include your own checks so that you get a warning if this is about to happen. If this is too vague an answer I will go back to my old notes and come up with something more precise.